# Grails 2.5.1 domain.get(id) get cached data

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm new in groovy and grails.
Grails version 2.5.1
Groovy version 2.4.5
My problem is:
I have an update method in customerController.

customerController:

```
def update(){
   def map = [:]
   def customerId = params.id
   def newCustomer = request.JSON
   def customer = customerService.updateCustomer(customerId, newCustomer)

   customer.validate()

   if (customer== null) {
       map['success'] = false
       map['message'] = "Record not found"

       return map
   }

   if (customer.save()) {
       map['success'] = true
       map['data'] = customer
   } else {
       validateErrorService.extractErrors(customer, map)
   }

   return map
}
```

In update method I call customerService.updateCustomer

customerService:

```
def updateCustomer(customerId, newCustomer){
    def customer = Customer.get(customerId)

    if (customer == null) {
        return null
    }
    verifyLead(newCustomer.leadId)

    customer.firstName = newCustomer.firstName
    customer.lastName = newCustomer.lastName
    if(!customer.hasErrors())
        customer.save(flush:true)

    return customer
}
```

Then i call verifyLead method to update Lead domain

```
def verifyLead(jsonLead, userId){
    Long leadId = jsonLead.id as Long
    Lead lead = Lead.get(leadId)

    lead.status = "Proceed"
    lead.save(flush: true)
}
```

In lead domain method 
Lead.get(leadId) return old(cached) data
So when i save:
lead.save(flush: true)
it error hibernate.object.staleException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm speculating here, because I don't know your setup)

Short answer:
Often a StaleObjectStateException (which I suppose you get) occurs when the database record behind a domain object (in your case the Lead) has been updated between the last time it is read from DB and your `save()` call.
Depending on your setup it could be a second instance of your Grails application.

One possible solution could be pessimistic locking (see [7.3.5 Pessimistic and Optimistic Locking](https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.5.1/guide/GORM.html#locking) in the Grails Documentation).

Longer answer (excuse me if you already know the more technical background):
`get()` returns a domain object from the underlaying Hibernate session. This session does not recognize changes in the database automatically.
So if the DB changes then data in your Hibernate session may get stale.
GORM (DB layer of Grails) normally uses optimistic locking (tries to save and increases the value the `version` field of the DB record).

If the version of the domain object your code tries to save is lesser than the version of the object in the db then GORM/Hibernate thinks better to throw an exception than to update the record and possibly destroy newer changes.

With pessimistic locking your code locks the DB record or table first, then updates the record, and at last releases the lock.

But be careful: pessimistic locking brings its own problems with it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Anyway is that problem solved in Grails 3.x?

Comment: Anyway Stefan, anyway ho to make sure Hibernate session recognize changes in database every time we call get()?

Comment: @sereyvuth-sok concerning Grails 3.x: sadly I still have to use Grails 2.x.
Concerning the session: The problem is more that the DB record is stale when `save`ing and less that it's stale when `get`ting it from the Hibernate session.